# Web testing and keeping track of areas tested

Tags: testing

I have a huge web application and I want to use a system which will help the developers keep track of areas (links) that have been visited and tested. I am not looking for a bug tracking system, etc. Just a system that will help me track pages that I have visited, etc.

Let me know if there is a tool to keep track of pages physically visited and signed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any out-of-the-box solution to do this.

If nothing comes up, you might be able to put something together using frames. You could have your site in the top frame, and the tracking application in a tiny bottom frame. The bottom frame would constantly update itself and tell you whether the URL in the big frame is in the list of visited pages. You would need some server side programming for that (e.g. PHP) and it would be some work, but nothing impossible.

Comment: upvoted, sounds really good, we could even put comments on the system which show up, something like google sidewiki

Answer (score 0):

I am also not aware of any Tools that are available for this. However, without any tools, you can still have developers give you a snapshot of browser history which shall give you this info. Alternatively depending on the webserver you are using, you can write simple scripts to scan through the access logs and generate a report of all the pages visited (uniquely and otherwise) and compare, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just track where you're visited you might consider pulling the data out from your browser history or, if you have access to them, server logs.

But I would consider writing, or recording—or creating somehow—actual automated tests for your web app esp. given its size.

SimpleTest provides a, now quite mature, [web tester](http://www.simpletest.org/en/web_tester_documentation.html). I heard things about it integrating with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). You can also use [Watir](http://watir.com/platforms/) which I know will run with Ruby but possibly more than that. Watir has the advantage that you can test multiple browsers. I'm sure there are [plenty more tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_testing) if you do a few searches.